# How to pass slots to a programatically created vuejs component instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My app requires creating dynamic component instances, for which I am using the following method:

```
import Button from 'Button.vue'
...
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Button);
var instance = new Ctor({ propsData: {} });
instance.$mount('#el');
```

All this works fine, I am able to pass props too. But now I need to pass slots to that instance too. I have tried random unsuccessful things like:

```
var instance = new Ctor({ propsData: {}, slots: { default: someNode }});
```

I have searched everywhere and have no clue if that is even possible or not. Any pointers?

Comment: Have you looked into using [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots)? You should be able to forward child properties via the binding you've assigned to `slot-scope`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slots can be set on the created instance by manipulating the `$slots` key:

```
import Button from 'Button.vue'
...
var ButtonConstructor = Vue.extend(Button);
var instance = new ButtonConstructor({ propsData: {} });

// SET SLOT
instance.$slots.default = [ 'Hello' ];

instance.$mount('#el');
```

Answer (score 4):

> From [How to create Vue.js slot programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150668/how-to-create-vue-js-slot-programatically)

I looked into TypeScript definition files of `Vue.js` and I found an undocumented function on Vue component instance: `$createElement()`. My guess is, it is the same function that is passed to `render(createElement)` function of the component. So, I am able to solve it as:

```
const Constr = Vue.extend(MyComponent);
const instance = new Constr({
    propsData: { someProp: 'My Heading' }
});

// Creating simple slot
const node = instance.$createElement('div', ['Hello']);
instance.$slots.default = [node];

instance.$mount(body);
```

But this is clearly undocumented and hence questionable approach. I will not mark it answered if there is some better approach available.