# How to create Vue.js slot programmatically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following component with a slot:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>{{ someProp }}</h2>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

For some reasons, I have to manually instantiate this component. This is how I am doing it:

```
const Constr = Vue.extend(MyComponent);
const instance = new Constr({
    propsData: { someProp: 'My Heading' }
}).$mount(body);
```

**The problem is: I am not able to create slot contents programmatically.** So far, I can create simple string based slot:

```
const Constr = Vue.extend(MyComponent);
const instance = new Constr({
    propsData: { someProp: 'My Heading' }
});

// Creating simple slot
instance.$slots.default = ['Hello'];

instance.$mount(body);
```

**The question is - how can I create `$slots` programmatically and pass it to the instance I am creating using `new`?**

*Note: I am not using a full build of Vue.js (runtime only). So I don't have a Vue.js compiler available to compile the template on the fly.*

Comment: I've found in a tutorial for unit tests in a Vue.js application that you can pass a `slot` argument in the `Vue.extend`. In this example, the author uses **vue-test-utils** but I think you can try to add a `slots` property in your constructor. Source : https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/10/02/Test-Vue-js-Slots-in-Jest/#Testing-Slots

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasFerro. I tried this but it doesn't work. It seems to be using some undocumented internal API.

Comment: As I said, he's using *vue-test-utils*. I'm trying to do the trick with `Vue.extend()`

Comment: I'm don't know whether this is the correct way so I only post this as a comment... You can assign Vnodes to $slots.default (I've found this info here https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/)  and you can create vnodes with the this.$createElement (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) I've modified the example from the CSS tricks example which shows how it can be done: https://codesandbox.io/s/jl66zxnwz9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue pass slot template to extended component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041145/vue-pass-slot-template-to-extended-component)

Comment: @nemesv, Yes that is the thing I landed up with. But $createElement is undocumented.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I looked into TypeScript definition files of `Vue.js` and I found an undocumented function on Vue component instance: `$createElement()`. My guess is, it is the same function that is passed to `render(createElement)` function of the component. So, I am able to solve it as:

```
const Constr = Vue.extend(MyComponent);
const instance = new Constr({
    propsData: { someProp: 'My Heading' }
});

// Creating simple slot
const node = instance.$createElement('div', ['Hello']);
instance.$slots.default = [node];

instance.$mount(body);
```

But this is clearly undocumented and hence questionable approach. I will not mark it answered if there is some better approach available.

Comment: Its not a questionable approach (or rather, not a private function)

As discussed here:
https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/issues/658#issuecomment-267465006

Answer (score 5):

I think I have finally stumbled on a way to programmatically create a slot element. From what I can tell, the approach does not seem to work for functional components. I am not sure why.

If you are implementing your own render method for a component, you can programmatically create slots that you pass to child elements using the createElement method (or whatever you have aliased it to in the render method), and passing a data hash that includes { slot: NAME_OF_YOUR_SLOT } followed by the array of children within that slot.

For example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false;

Vue.component('parent', {
  render (createElement) {
    return createElement('child', [
      createElement('h1', { slot: 'parent-slot' }, 'Parent-provided Named Slot'),
      createElement('h2', { slot: 'default' }, 'Parent-provided Default Slot')
    ])
  }
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div><slot name="parent-slot" /><slot /></div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<parent />'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*(This doesn't really answer `How to create Vue.js slot programatically?`. But it does solve your problem.)*

This trick is less hackish compared to using `$createElement()`.

Basically, create a new component that register `MyComponent` as a local component.

```
const Constr = Vue.extend({
  template: `
  <MyComponent someProp="My Heading">
    <div>slot here !!!</div>
  </MyComponent>
  `,
  components: {
    MyComponent: MyComponent
  }
});
const instance = new Constr().$mount('#app');
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/shrn26p1/

Comment: It works but I need Vuejs full build (Vue + compiler) for this to work. And yes, it feels a bit less hackish with a cost of an extra component.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across an answer to this in vue forum:
[slots](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/scoped-slot-in-render-function-with-default-content/8201)

The principle is: There is nothing like createElement('slot'..)
Instead there is a render function which provides the *slotted* innerHtml as function:
$scopedSlots.default()

Usage:

```js
render: function (createElement) {
  const self = this;
  return createElement("div", this.$scopedSlots.default());
}
```

If you want to provide a default in case there is no content given for the slots, you need to code a disctinction yourself and render something else.
(The link above holds a more detailed example)

The function returns an array, therefore it can not be used as a root for the render function. It need to be wrapped into single container node like *div* in the example above.